# TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined at App React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Whenever I console log `props.match.params`, I get an error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined` at App. I'm not sure this is relevant, but even if I console.log(props) I get four empty arrays.
Here is all the relevant code:

## Home.js

```
import React from "react";
import App from "./App";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <App />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/:roomCode" component={App} />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

## App.js (only the relevant part)

```
const App = (props) => {

  console.log(props.match.params);

};

export default App;
const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
render(<App />, appDiv);
```

I have been trying to figure this out for the past two days. Nothing works. Also, history.push also doesn't work, returns a very similar error. I have a feeling react-router-dom is broken in my project.
Help is much appreciated.

Edit:
Here is the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-microservice-iosu2?file=/src/App.js

Comment: would you show us how you change the route to App? does that work right?

Comment: it does work right, I used an alternative ```window.location.pathname.split("/")[1]``` and everything was working fine, but then I decided to use props.match.params, so yeah, everything is working with the routing to App

Comment: Because you didn't pass any props in the <App />

Comment: There is difference between `<Route exact path="/" component={App} />` and `<Route exact path="/" ><App /></Route>`

Comment: I am following tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H9rHrlNTpq8&list=PLzMcBGfZo4-kCLWnGmK0jUBmGLaJxvi4j&index=7&ab_channel=TechWithTim and in the video he did it the same as I am, and the props.match.params is working fine for him, so I assume I don't have to explicitly pass props to App

Comment: a sandbox would be more useful

Comment: I am not sure how that works, can you direct me to how to make one?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-microservice-iosu2?file=/src/App.js
there it is, it doesn't even work here, so it's definitely not a problem with my installed packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Home` Component is the root of all your components so it needs to be pass to `render` function not your `App` which is a descendent of `Home`.

after that change you need to change this line in your `Home` Component:

```
<Route exact path="/" render={(props) => <App {...props} />} />
```

```
import React from "react";
import App from "./App";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => <App {...props} />} />
        <Route path="/:roomCode" component={App} />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

here is how to render it:

```
const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
render(<Home />, appDiv);
```

now you can get the `props`

```
const App = (props) => {
  console.log(props.match.params);
};

export default App;
```

Comment: did you mean to add two of the renders in <Home /> or is that a mistake?

Comment: either way, I still get the same error :/

Comment: @MicasiO No, that was a typo. I mean you need to render `Home` Component and change the `Route` that is used for `App`, try it again with the above code

Comment: I noticed, that if I render only the Home.js and not the App.js, I get a blank page, no errors. But when I render both Home and App, I still get the error TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined
    at App

Comment: I am so sorry! Everything works now, I just had to edit the index.js file, I was rendering the wrong component! Thank you so much, sorry for causing such a fuss.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the React hooks provided by the React Router framework. There are several different hooks used to interact with the router.

```js
  const App = () => {
    const { roomCode } = useParams()
    console.log(params);
  };
```

[More info here](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks)

Comment: I tried that before, then I get an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
    at useParams